# DAX expression to create a new column in your Date table that breaks down the dates into weekly periods starting from Sunday and ending on Saturday

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cjIq.png)
I do like being able to “Open” up the week to see the 7 days underneath it.

I am trying to have my date table in power bi broken down into weekly basis.
I have written a DAX to this effect but i have an error I  cannot seem to figure out.
The last part of the date for this week is showing this " 04/01/2023 - 12/29/1899".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to work with the 'start of the week' day and use that as your date reference.

Try this:

StartWeekDay = Table[date] - WEEKDAY(Table[date], 2)